# WooCommerce Webhooks JSON parse using PHP Object - Array

Tags: php, json, woocommerce, webhooks

I create a PHP script that receive an hooks from WooCommerce, makes PDF with received data and send an e-mail, but I have a problem parsing the JSON data...
This is the JSON:

```
 {"id":128705,"parent_id":0,"number":"128705","order_key":"wc_order_5ae3648deddcd","created_via":"checkout","version":"3.3.5","status":"on-hold","currency":"EUR","date_created":"2018-04-27T19:57:33","date_created_gmt":"2018-04-27T17:57:33","date_modified":"2018-04-27T19:57:34","date_modified_gmt":"2018-04-27T17:57:34","discount_total":"0","discount_tax":"0","shipping_total":"0","shipping_tax":"0","cart_tax":"0","total":"50","total_tax":"0","prices_include_tax":false,"customer_id":7,"customer_ip_address":"79.43.191.213","customer_user_agent":"mozilla\/5.0 (x11; linux x86_64) applewebkit\/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome\/62.0.3202.89 safari\/537.36","customer_note":"","billing":{"first_name":"Nicola","last_name":"Giada","company":"","address_1":"V","address_2":"","city":"CANIC","state":"RA","postcode":"48018","country":"IT","email":"ggggggg@gmail.com","phone":"30002222"},"shipping":{"first_name":"","last_name":"","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":""},"payment_method":"bacs","payment_method_title":"Bonifico bancario","transaction_id":"","date_paid":null,"date_paid_gmt":null,"date_completed":null,"date_completed_gmt":null,"cart_hash":"dba69b53a4a39c58c83b3e557e818bb7","meta_data":[{"id":1383502,"key":"_billing_data","value":"00\/00\/1990"},{"id":1383503,"key":"_billing_codice_fiscale","value":"GDDLLLL333232"},{"id":1383504,"key":"_billing_socio","value":"Sono gi\u00e0 Socio"},{"id":1383505,"key":"_billing_dati","value":"Acconsento"},{"id":1383506,"key":"billing_data","value":"00\/00\/1990"},{"id":1383507,"key":"billing_codice_fiscale","value":"GDDLLLL333232"},{"id":1383508,"key":"billing_socio","value":"Sono gi\u00e0 Socio"},{"id":1383509,"key":"billing_dati","value":"Acconsento"}],"line_items":[{"id":94,"name":"Object buyed XXXX 2018","product_id":128683,"variation_id":128684,"quantity":1,"tax_class":"","subtotal":"40","subtotal_tax":"0","total":"40","total_tax":"0","taxes":[],"meta_data":[{"id":883,"key":"corso","value":"Object NUED"}],"sku":"","price":40},{"id":95,"name":"SECOND OBJECT","product_id":126454,"variation_id":0,"quantity":1,"tax_class":"","subtotal":"10","subtotal_tax":"0","total":"10","total_tax":"0","taxes":[],"meta_data":[],"sku":"","price":10}],"tax_lines":[],"shipping_lines":[],"fee_lines":[],"coupon_lines":[],"refunds":[]}
```

And this is the piece of my PHP where I retrieve information from the JSON:

```
/* Gestione dei dati via JSON */
$year = date('Y'); //Anno validità associativa
$secret = 'xxxxx'; //La chiave per il Webhook generata da Woocommerce 
$JSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($JSON);
$sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $secret, true));
if ($sig != $header_sig) print 'Firma invalida'; //Controllo la firma di sicurezza. Mettere die invece di print.

$nome = $data->billing->first_name;
$cognome = $data->billing->last_name;
$nato_luogo = '';
$prov = $data->billing->state;
$cap = $data->billing->postcode;
$indirizzo = $data->billing->address_1;
//$indirizzo .= $data->billing->address_2;
$tel = $data->billing->phone;
$email = $data->billing->email;
$data = date('d/m/Y'); //Data sottoscrizione scheda
$residenza = $data->billing->city;

//Valori dentro i meta_data personalizzati
foreach ($data->meta_data as $datum) {
if ($datum->key == "_billing_data") $nato_data = $datum->value; 
if ($datum->key == "_billing_codice_fiscale") $CF = $datum->value; 
if ($datum->key == "_billing_socio") $checksocio = $datum->value; 
}
if($check_socio == 'S\u00ec') print 'Gi&aacute; socio';
```

My problem is getting values inside "meta_data", the: foreach isn't working at all.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly makes you say that it "isn't working at all"? What do you _expect_ to happen?  What is _actually_ happening?  What debugging have you done?  From a quick test, the `foreach` itself works just fine.

Comment: `$data = date('d/m/Y'); //Data sottoscrizione scheda`  TYPO

Comment: the 3 variables which I should get inside the foreach ($nato_data, $CF, $checksocio) are NULL, it seems I actually parse the JSON code not correctly ... but I can't understand why.
The rest is globally working, but the foreach doesn't retrieve what I want from the JSON.

Comment: See my second comment.

Comment: @PatrickQ ... it's typographic italian style to print a data .. DD/MM/YYYY ...

Comment: The problem is the _foreach_, probably (for sure) I make a mistake ... but I couldn't understand which.

Comment: I'll tell you one more time, look at my second comment.  _Really_ look at it.  See that variable you're using?  Can you see why doing `foreach ($data->meta_data as $datum)` after that won't work?

Comment: @PatrickQ I'm an idiot. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in naming the variable $data ... TYPO error. Thanks.